# Support for both map and cache in Hazelcast client-server setup

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap, jcache

I have a scenario where I have deployed a Hazelcast Server which should support both IMap and Icache. One client need to store as ICache for RateLimiter scenario and another client need to store it as IMap. But when I have one Client as Icache, another client also should be changed to Icache. Below exception occurred when I tried to store as IMap.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-04-24T06:34:12.099+0000 ERROR o.s.b.SpringApplication:reportFailure:821 -  -  | - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.cache.CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.cache.CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.impl.ClientServiceNotFoundException: No factory registered for service: hz:impl:cacheService
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:296) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar!/:2.7.9]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar!/:2.7.9]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar!/:2.7.9]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar!/:2.7.9]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar!/:2.7.9]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar!/:2.7.9]
```

I tried switching to different Hazelcast versions.

Comment: Does it work if you remove Actuate ?

Comment: @NeilStevenson just tried removing the actuator. It worked well. But I need the actuator to be part of the deployment for monitoring purposes. Is there any alternate way to include it? I have excluded the CacheMetricsAutoConfiguration class as a temporary solution.